# ¿Porqué este evento no produce nada?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, videojs

Estoy utilizando la plataforma Stremeable y la api de player.js (https://playerjs.io/). 
Tengo el siguiente código, el cual funciona por que reproduce el video de forma automática e imprime en la consola que el video se está reproduciendo, pero al finalizar el video, no pasa nada. Intenté de varias maneras pero no resultó ninguna.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prueba</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="modal fade" id="admodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="admodal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Puede que te interese</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div style="width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:56.250%;">
                        <iframe src="https://streamable.com/s/je801/cfxnoe" class="adplayer" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" id="adplayer" allowfullscreen style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.embed.ly/player-0.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function adend() {
            $('#admodal').modal('toggle');
            console.log('video ended');
        }

        $('iframe.adplayer').each(function(){

        // initialize the player.
        var player = new playerjs.Player(this);
        var receiver = new playerjs.Receiver(this);

        // Wait for the player to be ready.
        player.on('ready', function(){

            // Listen to the play event.
            player.on('play', function(){
                console.log('Ad Started');
                $('#admodal').modal('toggle');
            });

            //autoplay the video.
            player.play();
        });

        player.on("ended", function(){
            console.log('video ended');
            $('#admodal').modal('toggle');
            receiver.emit('ended');
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Y que se supone que debe de hacer cuando finalice?

Comment: Tiene que imprimir en la consola "video ended" y ocultar el modal de bootstrap

Comment: Puedes agregar  el html  de tu código  y las referencias  de script que usas para reproducir el error.

Comment: Listo! Ya agregué el código para reproducir el error